# how to select given element AND all its children simultaneously?

Tags: css, css-selectors

ok I know how to do both these things separately:

```
#elemID {  } /* selects only one element */
#elemID * {  } /* selects all its children elements but not the element itself */
```

And I know I can do it like this:

```
#elemID, #elemID * { }
```

But is there a way to avoid this repeating ?

Comment: CSS properties generally inherit. Are you sure that you need to apply the rule to the ancestors, too?

Comment: Asterisk in CSS should be mostly avoided too.

Comment: Re: CSS property inheritance – most do not, unless you count font, color and some other properties. Margin, padding, backgrounds aren't inherited by default, only if specified explicitly.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2020?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is nothing shorter than that.

Note that if you really only want all the **children** of `#elemID`, and not all the **descendants**, you need to use the child combinator:

```
#elemID, #elemID > *
```

And as Šime Vidas has commented, some properties like `color` are automatically inherited by descendant elements by default. If you're trying to give text color to `#elemID`, you should not need to apply it explicitly and recursively to the elements inside it. See the [SitePoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritance) on inheritance in CSS for details.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you could select its parent if an equivalent selector exists:

```
.parent * { ... }
```

Comment: That does not select the parent.

Comment: I did say *if the parent has an equivalent selector*. If there were a uniquely identifiable parent, then you could select that parent as the base of the selector and use the asterisk.